# Issue with CodeIgniter subquery

Tags: codeigniter

```
$query=$this->db->query('SELECT g.gallery_id, g.gallery_title, (
                           SELECT i.gallery_image_path
                           FROM nepal_gallery_image AS i
                           WHERE i.gallery_id = g.gallery_id
                           AND i.gallery_image_status =  "Enabled"
                           LIMIT 0 , 1) AS gallery_image_path
                         FROM nepal_gallery AS g
                         WHERE g.gallery_status =  "Enabled"');
```

The above query gives the correct output.

However, when I use the CI subquery library:

```
$this->load->library('Subquery');
$this->db->select('g.gallery_id,g.gallery_title');
$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('select');
$sub ->select('i.gallery_image_path')
     ->from('nepal_gallery_image AS i')                 
     ->where(array('i.gallery_image_status'=>"Enabled",  
                   'i.gallery_id'=>"g.gallery_id")) 
     ->limit(0,1);
$this->subquery->end_subquery('gallery_image_path'); 
$this->db->from('nepal_gallery AS g');
$this->db->where('g.gallery_stats',"Enabled");
$query=$this->db->get();
```

the resulting query is:

```
SELECT `g`.`gallery_id` , `g`.`gallery_title` , (
  SELECT `i`.`gallery_image_path`
  FROM (`nepal_gallery_image` AS i)
  WHERE `i`.`gallery_image_status` = 'Enabled'
  AND `i`.`gallery_id` = 'g.gallery_id'
  LIMIT 0 , 1 ) AS gallery_image_path
FROM (`nepal_gallery` AS g)
WHERE `g`.`gallery_status` = 'Enabled'
```

and the output is not as expected.

the output in first query is

```
    <table>
     <tr>
         <th> gallery_id</th>
         <th> gallery_title</th>
         <th> gallery_image_path </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Gallery 1</td>
        <td>images/image1.jpg</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Gallery 2</td>
        <td>images/image2.jpg</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

However, in later query, the output is

```
    <table>
     <tr>
         <th> gallery_id</th>
         <th> gallery_title</th>
         <th> gallery_image_path </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Gallery 1</td>
        <td>NULL</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Gallery 2</td>
        <td>NULL</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

It seems the problem is with the subquery.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, but in what way is it not as expected precisely?

Comment: the output in first query is
        gallery_id     gallery_title     gallery_image_path
        1              Gallery 1         images/gallery1_1234.jpg
        2              Gallery 2         images/gallery2_1234.jpg

However, in later query, the output is
        gallery_id     gallery_title     gallery_image_path
         1              Gallery 1         NULL
         2              Gallery 2         NULL

It seems the problem is with the subquery.

Comment: i think you should add that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the subqueries where condition is taking your table alias `g` as string `'g.gallery_id'` one way to avoid the CI's protect fields is by   passing third parameter as false in where condition so CI will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

try this

```
 $sub ->select('i.gallery_image_path')
 ->from('nepal_gallery_image AS i')                 
 ->where(array('i.gallery_image_status'=>"Enabled",  
               'i.gallery_id'=>"g.gallery_id"), NULL, FALSE);
                                           //--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--here 
 ->limit(0,1);
```

**or the simply write your clauses manaully**

```
  $where = "i.gallery_id = g.gallery_id AND i.gallery_image_status =  'Enabled'";
  $sub ->select('i.gallery_image_path')
 ->from('nepal_gallery_image AS i')                 
 ->where($where,NULL,FALSE); 
 ->limit(0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ->where(array('i.gallery_image_status'=>"Enabled",  
               'i.gallery_id'=>"g.gallery_id"))
```

The problem is with 'i.gallery_id'=>"g.gallery_id" - CI is building the query with "g.gallery_id" as being a literal String... when it aught to be a table column reference. If you manually replace - "g.gallery_id"  with  'g'.'gallery_id'  it should serve as a demonstration.

If you don't know how to remedy that, please leave a comment. (it may just be a matter of using single quotes).

Comment: using Single quote did not help. The problem remained the same.

Comment: The solution by bipen provides the method of fixing the problem indicated above.